# specific menu options in tkinter using classes

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I have searched far and wide for this but could not quite get a full answer based on what I found.
I'm writing a GUI in Python3 using tkinter. Everything is going to be in classes including a 'Menu' class.
Couple issues - I want to use a for loop to populate my menu items and sub items (not implemented yet).
 - I want to do this for each frame that the 'container' class displays but I want certain items in the menus to be disabled (greyed out) when those options do not apply. i.e. Start of the program with nothing loaded the 'Save' button would not make sense so I would disable it until a 'New' project is made or an existing one opened.

My code so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Menu


class MainFrame(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)


        #display manubar
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button.pack()
        button1.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page Two", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button.pack()
        button1.pack()


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File",underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Page One", underline=0,
                             command=self.onexit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Page Two", underline=1,
                             command=lambda:self.onexit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.onexit)


    def onexit(self):
        quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainFrame()
    app.mainloop()
```

How do you call the 'PageOne' or 'Pagetwo' using the options in the file menu? For testing purposes, I am just exiting the program for now so I can run the program without errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I saw a question in your question. Are you asking how to get your menu item that says "Page Two" to display the `PageTwo` frame?

Comment: Also, we don't wan to know the whole scope of the project. That is irrelevant in most cases. What we need instead is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, we don't need the copyright or the different fonts or the background images to solve the problem of showing a frame from a menu.

Comment: It's my first post on stackoverflow. I have edited my question/code as per your comment. Hope this satisfies you a little bit :). Thanks for your tips. I still need to learn a lot, future questions will be more up to stackoverflow standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I am not sure how to call the 'PageOne' or 'Pagetwo' using the options in the file menu...

Just like with your pages, the `MenuBar` object needs to be given a reference to the controller so that it can call the controller function `show_frame`. Since `MainFrame` is both the "parent" and the "controller", you can use the one argument for both purposes.

```
class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.controller = parent
        ...
        fileMenu.add_command(..., command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        fileMenu.add_command(..., command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I made my changes to the code and it works. I was missing  the `self.controller = parent` line. I am very new to classes so when doing inheritance and sub classes and whatnot I still get easily confused.